# Call the method from one viewController while displaying the another one

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates

I have the fullscreen `MapViewController` and `LisViewController` which is displaying in **popover**. So ListViewController is the `TableView` and I need by clicking on the cell show the callout for the different points (which represented in rows of the table). For this moment I can't solve this..

In my listViewController I've implemented

```
// LisViewController.h

@protocol ListViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)showCalloutForObjectId:(id) objectId;

@end 

@interface ListViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) id delegate;

@end

// ListViewController.m

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder: aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        self.delegate = [MapViewController new];  // I BELIEVE THE PROBLEM IS HERE - CAN'T GET THE INSTANCE OF THE PRESENT VIEW CONTROLLER
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary * data = [self.dataSet dataFromIndex: indexPath.row];
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(showCalloutForObjectId:)])
    {
        [self.delegate showCalloutForObjectId: data[@"object_id"]];
    }
}
```

So the method in my MapViewController is never called - any help?

Comment: `[MapViewController new]` - is `new` a method in MapViewController? From what i understand, you want to navigate from `ListViewController` to `MapViewController` by dismissing the `ListViewController` which is a popover and show something on Map through `MapViewController` based on the selected cell in `ListViewController` - right? can you post code of `MapViewController`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must assign `ListViewController` delegate property in your `MapViewController`

In your `MapViewController` after you instantiate `ListViewController`:

```
ListViewController *lvc = [ListViewController alloc] init]; 
lvc.delegate = self;
```

And of cause you need to implement

```
-(void)showCalloutForObjectId:(id) objectId;
```

in your `MapViewController`

Comment: Great! Thanks.. I believe I never understand, how to implement the delegates correctly..(